# What is a Task in Java?

Tags: java, concurrency

Java supports application to run asynchronous tasks through various mechanisms, what exactly is a task? JavaDocs: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html

Comment: @AlexanderHeim Well not really. A thread can run several tasks, it's not a 1-to-1 mapping. Task is just a unit of work in the abstract sense. You could have for example `Runnable` or `Callable` instances as tasks, with a threadpool for running them asynchronously.

Comment: @Kayaman That´s why I said pretty much as in similar. But of course you´re right, it´s not the same thing.

Comment: @AlexanderHeim Yes, I have heard about threads. Also, a better link to know what are threads: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/procthread.html.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Task is just a unit of work in the abstract sense. You have tasks of some type, and then you have mechanisms to perform those tasks in an asynchronous way.

A simple example would be instances of `Runnable` or `Callable` (or even `FutureTask` if you want to have the name "task" in it) for the tasks, and an [ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) to run them.

Comment: An asynchronous task ("A something you need to be done in parallel") is normally performed via a thread in Java. Other ways to do it would be using java.lang.ProcessBuilder, Runtime.exec(), or fibers through Quasar or some other library.